# Using foreach statement and switch for checked multiple nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, switch-statement, nodes

I'm dealing on nodes, child nodes, child's child nodes in a TreeView list; not to mention, checkboxes. My goal is to select/check multiple nodes and each node linked to an exclusive code will execute with just a click of a button. I've thought of using foreach statement with switch and if statement within. **Foreach** to loop through the nodes of the treeview, **if** to check if the node is checked, and **switch** to browse through the case values that match the checked node. That's my idea, but I feel there's a better one for it. Could someone verify the program below or provide an easier, cleaner version of it?

My idea: To do it like this:

```
foreach (TreeNode rootNodes in treeView1.Nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode childNodes in rootNodes.Nodes)
    {
        if (childNodes.Checked == true)
        {
            switch (childNodes.Name.ToString())
            {
                case "Trial A":
                    //execute code for Trial A
                    MessageBox.Show("A"); //trial
                    break;
                case "Trial B":
                    //execute code for Trial B
                    MessageBox.Show("B"); //trial
                    break;
                case "Trial C":
                    //execute code for Trial C
                    MessageBox.Show("C"); //trial
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far when I tried this, it worked. When I selected multiple nodes, each node's code ran one at a time. Made me kind of overjoyed, actually. The problem lies within me, there's this nagging feeling that this program may be potentially incorrect or I may encounter problems in the future.

I'm using VS 2005, .NET 2.0 working on WinForms.
*Sidenote: I parsed an xml file to  treeview list. Nodes correspond to the objects within the xml file.*

*Another sidenote: I'm still learning. I'm a newbie. Definitely a C# newbie. As for other programming experiences, I know a bit of C and C++ (but just the basics, just for some exercises and projects in school).*

Comment: does this code even run? am not sure if it compiles even ?!  `foreach (childNodes.Checked in rootNodes)` !!

Comment: The two things that probably are nagging at your programmer's bone are a) that you can't be sure of the depth the tree might grow to and b) that the case structure doesn't lend itself well to adding real code.  For a) you need recursion as in Neill's answer for b) you can use delegates and maybe create a dictionary<uniqueID, delegate or action>..

Comment: @chouaib, I edited it now. I didn't realize that I pasted the other code (obviously the incorrect one) here, I was experimenting it. I changed it now to the working one. I think.

Comment: A's definitely right. I can see that it's gonna be so long already. As for the B, I've been doing trial and errors, add and delete stuff just so that it would work. I'll keep that in mind, I'll search and research about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly is that you can have an undefined hierarchical depth of nodes. In that case you need to perform recursion:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes) RecurseTree(node);

private void RecurseTree(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Checked == true)
    {
        switch (node.Name)
        {
            case "Trial A":
                //execute code for Trial A
                MessageBox.Show("A"); //trial
                break;
            case "Trial B":
                //execute code for Trial B
                MessageBox.Show("B"); //trial
                break;
            case "Trial C":
                //execute code for Trial C
                MessageBox.Show("C"); //trial
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("error");
                break;
        }
    }

    foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes) RecurseTree(childNode);
}
```

Comment: That is true, I have quite a number of nodes at hand and it's making me cry thinking that I have to type (cough, copy and paste) them all.
One thing I'm concerned about this is that this may not be compatible with the version I'm using knowing var was introduced at around .NET 3.0 or 3.5? I'm not sure. Could you possibly provide one compatible with .NET 2.0? Thanks.

Comment: The concept of recursion stays the same, you can just replace 'var' with the classname which in your case is surely TreeNode. I'll update the example for you.

Comment: This code will work only if all node names are different. If there are identical names (from different parent nodes) then the function should build a path from names, and use paths in `switch`.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I agree. The OP should rather use TreeNode.FullPath  property.

Comment: "var" is a C# (3.0+) keyword, not a .NET one; then you can use it with any .NET version you pick, as long as you are using C# 3.0 or greater (VS 2008 and later).

Comment: there's no definition for `node.Children.` Where did that come from? I don't know what to do with it. Is it the same with `node.Nodes`?

Comment: @Dialecticus it's a good thing that all the node names I'm dealing with are all different.

Comment: I got it, thanks @NeillVerreynne. And it functioned the same way it did with the code I showed. And the difference between them is?

Comment: @Kurisuchin, the difference is with recursion it will check node.Nodes[n].Nodes[n] up to a leave-node (leave node has no children nodes). Your code were only running through all the nodes on the top level  and their child nodes (depth/level 1) and ignoring any other nodes on any other subsequent levels/depths.

Comment: You mean to say I don't have to type everything in down to the farthest level because I was definitely planning on doing that. @NeillVerreynne

Comment: It depends on what you are referring to when saying typing everything. If you are talking about the switch statement the way you are doing it, yes. But this is a poor implementation (the switch). You should rather explain what you want to do exactly. @TaW, gave you one option for the switch and that is rather to use a dictionary with delegates....

Comment: Well, I don't know if I mentioned it, but within my xml file is a long list of elements including parent nodes and its child nodes and so on. I searched about the delegates @Taw suggested and it looked like a good solution. I talked to my senior about the code I developed and he suggested that I shouldn't rely on the switch and hard-coded statements calling on elements within the xml but instead try to work on something similar to placeholders or the like. It's all confusing to me.